# is .net ( or any part of it ) open source?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

is any code related to .NET/ASP.NET or BCL open source? If so where can this be downloaded?

Comment: yes, quite a bit is (e.g. ASP.NET MVC, NETMF, ...) take a look at what's on http://www.codeplex.com/ which includes MS and non-MS projects. Also mono includes a number of .NET APIs http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Jul-07.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the .NET framework 'open source'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961473/is-the-net-framework-open-source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's implementation of the CLR is not open source. However, a stripped down version of it, [Rotor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotor_%28software_project%29), is.

That said, Mono is probably better supported when compared with Rotor, so if you're looking for something to distribute I'd use Mono.

Answer (score 6):

There is the [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), which is an open-source cross-platform *implementation* of .NET, but the "standard" Microsoft implementation is not free-to-copy.

Comment: +1 -- note that Microsoft "unofficially" supports Mono, so incompatibilities between Microsoft's implementation of the CLR and Mono are unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

The source code is [*available*](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx), but it is not open-source, per se. There are, however, open source projects available that use the framework (see sourceforge).

Answer (score 0):

Well the .net framework was ported to Mono for Mac and Unix so I would have to say all of it is open source.

Comment: Not to mention you can get the code to every single class in the frame work using reflection on the DLL to see just how it works

Comment: It was NOT ported, it was re-implemented by a different developer team entirely.

Comment: You don't even need reflection - they'll give you the source to read.  It's the "writing" part that's the sticking point.

Comment: Reflection cannot be used to get the source code. Reflection gives information about metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework is not open-source. But [up to .NET 2.0 it is ECMA compilant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), meaning it is free to develop and commercialize your applications.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC is open source, and the SC is freely available.

Answer (score 0):

.Net is open source in the sense that, yes, you can view the source for most of the base class library.  It is not open source in that you are not allowed to submit patches or fork the code into your own project.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released a subset called [.net micro framework](http://www.netmf.com/Home.aspx) for embedded development.